# Clearing Caches of ObservableRangeCollections

Tags: maui

I must admit that the subject of my question may sound peculiar, yet it has a rationale behind it.

I have an `ObservableRangCollection<StoreSelection>` with some elements. Previously, I used `.Clear()` to delete all elements and add new elements using `.AddRange(...)` with elements filtered from another collection which identified the selected elements before adding them. So, the `ObservableRangeCollection<StoreSelection>` had all selected elements and was bound to a `CollectionView`.

I identified a negative behavior with this or let's say a "Bug". Doing this I identified increased memory consumption and rising number of registered handlers in the delegate Binding of the `PropertyChanged` event. There it still kept the registered handlers after using `.Clear()` and so I got more and more registered delegates increasing memory consumption and lead to a crash in the end that just closed the App (see question [Rising memory consumption and rising number of Handlers in PropertyChanged event handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77753178/rising-memory-consumption-and-rising-number-of-handlers-in-propertychanged-event?noredirect=1#comment137118430_77753178)).

Due to this, I had to use `.RemoveAt(i)` to clear all Elements within a loop instead of using `.Clear()` which kind of solved the problem.

Unfortunately, I now have another negative behavior due to this. Using method `.Clear()` also cleared the values in my Entrys that were bound. Now using `.RemoveAt(i)`, I detected another negative behavior that I do not and did not have using `.Clear()`. Using `.RemoveAt(i)`, it seems like the values of my Entrys are still kind of cached and every second `OnPropertyChanged(...)` shows the old values even if they cannot be seen in Debug-Mode when I look at all my values in the collection. Anyway, they appear then in the `CollectionView` that is bound to this collection. I also tried to overwrite my values and again setting them to "0" for instance, but this did not help.

I tried and used `.Clear()` after my `.RemoveAt(i)` loop finished. Then, I can't see old values in this case anymore. But, the `CollectionView` that is bound to this `ObservableRangeCollection` flickers and is even empty for a short period. This is not the case when just using `.RemoveAt(i)` without the `.Clear()`. I also tried to use `new ObservableRangeCollection<StoreSelection>()`, but this is even worse as later on all values are not bound anymore and the update and displaying the values in my Entrys does not work then anymore.

Is there a way to clear the caches of the `ObservableRangeCollection` as is obviously done behind the scenes when using `.Clear()` and which I could call after using `.RemoveAt(i)` to delete all my elements so that my old values of bound Entrys are not showing up anymore after every 2nd `OnPropertyChange(...)` call on my `ObservableRangeCollection`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering the link to the demo project, from your linked question:

You have:

```
public ObservableRangeCollection<StoreSelection> SelectedStoreItems { get; set; }
```

This is observable, in terms of modifying the collection's content.
But it is not observable, if you change the collection itself.

You set it once, the values are shown, you can add/remove elements, it will show up.
But you have to use the same object in memory.

If you want to replace the object itself:

```
[ObservableProperty]
public ObservableRangeCollection<StoreSelection> _selectedStoreItems;
```

And then you will be able to:

```
SelectedStoreItems = new ObservableRangeCollection<StoreSelection>()
```

Your case is very interesting, on top of everything you connect it to IOS memory leaks (quite a lot at the moment). This answer will only fix your binding when assigning new list.

Comment: Well, I do not use a `new ObservableRangCollection<StoreSelection>()`, this was just to try if it works and may be misleading from my description. What I actually have is the effect that when I use `RemoveAt(i)` and add one of my elements again, it toggles showing the old values and the values I set to "0". So, you must imagine it like, I can see the Value "0" in Debugger, but in the UI it toggles between "0" and a former value from a previous selection, e.g. "200". When it was selected the first time, I add a value "200" to and Entry, unselect the store and select again and set value to "0"

Comment: But, do you recommend doing it like that in my case, should i use the `[ObservableProperty]` attribute and then set it to a `new` instance instead of using `.Clear()` or `.RemoveAt(i)`. The problem using `new` was the flicker effect and that the `CollectionView` in the UI was cleared (visibly for a user) and then filled with the new elements afterwards. Unfortunately, the type of the `ObservableRangeCollection<...>` is from a Type defined in a C# DLL project and not a MAUI DLL

Comment: @OXO If you do not plan to use it anymore, why not?

Comment: Well, it is working using a `[ObservableProperty]` as you described in your answer. Yes the problem under the hood is gone by this and the values are displayed correctly now. But, it is as I described, I can see that my collection view is cleared and empty for a period of time and then filled with the selected stores again then which was not there when I did not use `new ObservableRangCollection<StoreSelection>()` but just the `RemoveAt(i)`. Is there a way to prevent that? Or anything I can do? A user should not see that all his elements he selected updating completely

Comment: To sum it up: I did not just want to use `new ObservableRangeCollection<...>()` as it appears as if the PropertyChangedEvent delegates are then not unregistered correctly. I decided to remove them manually one by one. After that the issue was there that values are still "cached" and appear when my elements are selected again even if they are not available with these values in my collection anymore. To solve this, I used `.Clear()` after that. To prevent flicker of the `CollectionView`, I created my own `ObservableRangeCollection` as was done in Link below. But this is very slow in the UI

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3448736/updating-an-observablecollection-in-wpf-causes-screen-flicker-how-can-i-prevent

Comment: or would it even be better to switch to a normal `List<StoreSelection>` and do the `OnPropertyChanged(…)` after `.Clear()` and all that stuff? Right now it might be stupid what I am doing. After all that I call `OnPropertyChanged(…)` after the all the stuff I do on the `ObservableRangeCollection`. Normally, this shouldn’t be necessary, I would say and is waste of time?

Comment: @OXO nothing what you do is normally necessary. But then again, the memory leaks in MAUI are not normal either. If you are notifying everything manually, then yes, you might as well use List. The main benefit from ObservableCollection, is when modifying the content item by item. For everything else, it is plain and simple useless.

Comment: The question is still if I had the same issues without using a `ObservableRangeCollection`. But UI wise a `.Clear()` of a normal `List<StoreSelection>` in combination with a `OnPropertyChanged(..)` could prevent flickering in the UI I suppose. But, I am a bit concerned about the other Question regarding memory. The reason I used `RemoveAt(i)` was that via this the handlers got removed in combination with `GC.Collect()`. I ambit sure about that with a normal `List` as there is no notification mechanism unless I called `OnPropertyChanged(..)` for each Remove from this list